# Confusion regarding worker threads and request threads

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I've been reading "Spring in Action" and got confused by the following description of Servlet-based frameworks (emphasis mine):

> Typical Servlet-based web frameworks, such as Spring MVC, are blocking and multi-threaded in nature, using a *single thread per connection*. As requests are handled, a worker thread is pulled from a thread pool to process the request. Meanwhile, the *request thread* is blocked until it’s notified by the worker thread that it’s finished.

I was under the impression that servlet containers like Tomcat do something like this under the hood (very simplified, of course):

```
while (true) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    // the actual handling of request is done by Servlet-based framework and application code.
    workerThreadPool.submit(() -> handleRequest(socket));
}
```

I mean, we do not create a thread for each connection but reuse existing worker threads.

Also I'm not sure what a request thread is. I thought it could be the thread in which we `accept()` connections, but this thread doesn't block until request has been processed. My understanding is that with Spring Boot and embedded Tomcat worker threads are the ones with names http-nio-8889-exec-* (see VisualVM screenshot). What is the request thread here?

[image]

So, my questions are:

1. What important things are missing in the pseudocode above?
2. Does Spring MVC (or servlet container) actually create a *thread per each connection*?
3. What is the role of request thread (or threads) and who creates them? How can I identify them in a typical Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 0):

No sensible web server uses a thread per connection. Such a design won't scale with the number of connections.

> Typical Servlet-based web frameworks, such as Spring MVC, are blocking
> and multi-threaded in nature, using a single thread per connection. As
> requests are handled, a worker thread is pulled from a thread pool to
> process the request. Meanwhile, the request thread is blocked until
> it’s notified by the worker thread that it’s finished.

Even though they say 'thread per connection' the description talks about thread pools.

The thread that 'accepts', blocks on the selector. As soon as new TCP/IP connection is established, the accepting thread unblocks. I'm not sure about the implementation; but one way of dealing with is to detach the connection from the accepting selector and use one more selectors that wait for read/write events. Of course each of these selectors will have their own thread.

My guess is that the http-nio-8889-exec are the request threads. It has been a very long time I used Spring, but in the past, Spring just piggybacked on the threads provided by the servlet container.